# Why does dd sometimes not wait until data is written?

Tags: linux, command-line, dd

Sometimes, when I write images to a flash drive, this happens:

```
$ sudo dd if=install57.fs of=/dev/sdc
573440+0 records in
573440+0 records out
293601280 bytes (294 MB) copied, 0.549231 s, 535 MB/s
```

Basically, Linux caches everything, writes nothing, and `dd` exits. After I type `sync`, it starts writing the data (flash drive LED starts blinking).

Why does this happen?

Comment: Are you sure `/dev/sdc` is an actual device on your system and you aren't writing to a file `/dev/sdc`?  Do an `ls --color /dev` - `/dev/sdc` should be yellow if it's a device.

Answer (score 21):

Use this instead:

```
sudo dd if=install57.fs of=/dev/sdc conv=fsync
```

This calls the [`fsync()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync) after every [`write()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) system call. This forces `dd` not to cache anything. See this part of the manpage of fsync (`man 2 fsync`):

```
fsync() transfers ("flushes") all modified in-core data of (i.e., modified buffer cache 
pages for) the file referred to by the file descriptor fd to the disk device (or other 
permanent storage device) where that file resides. The call blocks until the device reports 
that the transfer has completed. It also flushes metadata information associated with the 
file (see stat(2)).
```

This is the kernels default behavior. Linux kernels manage write and read caches like this: When the `write()` syscall is issued, the data is quickly written to the cache and a write-completed status is sent to the process. When the buffer is needed or when there is free time on the bus, the data is written from the cache to the hard disk.

Comment: I like that your answer and mine cover almost entirely different approaches. Nice, +1.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton dito +1

Comment: all answers are good in this question.

Comment: @chaos Just to clarify: *This is the kernels default behavior.*-Do you mean that `conv=fsync` is default when writing to block devices such that `dd` does not cache anything? Looking for a good answer to this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312687/why-is-sync-so-important-when-making-a-bootable-linux-usb-stick/312766#312766

Answer (score 10):

This happens because Linux, and most other operating systems, cache both reads and writes. In most cases, this makes your operating system more responsive.

If you want to ensure the cached data has been written, you want to use `sync`, as you know. Linux exposes a significant number of settings you can tune as well. [This article](https://lonesysadmin.net/2013/12/22/better-linux-disk-caching-performance-vm-dirty_ratio/) gives a good overview of some settings. You could set the vm.dirty_background_bytes to 0, for example, to ensure the kernel kicks off the flusher threads immediately.

Answer (score 7):

> [sync(8) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sync) :
>
> The kernel keeps data in memory to avoid doing (relatively slow) disk
>   reads and writes. This improves performance, but if the computer
>   crashes, data may be lost or the file system corrupted as a result.
>   sync ensures that everything in memory is written to disk.

Note: `unmount` (or eject) automatically calls `sync` which "hides" this in normal filesystem usage.