# dd function seems to freeze when done

Tags: linux, arch-linux, dd

I'm trying to copy an iso on a usb stick with this command:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=lubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdc status=progress
```

What is quite straight forward. The iso is 912M big in size. Why does the output text freeze here instead of ending the program?

```
956301312 bytes (956 MB, 912 MiB) copied, 11.216 s, 85.3 MB/s
```

I can't even stop the program from running with `ctr-c`.

Comment: Can you confirm the data is not still being transferred? (tools: `iotop`, `iostat -d 1`). Is `85.3 MB/s` a realistic transfer rate for your USB stick and USB port? It looks as if `dd` waited for some buffer to flush, but I would expect it to exit anyway like [in this question](https://superuser.com/q/960734/432690). Did it exit eventually?

Comment: It exits eventually, but minutes later. The transfer rate changes to a way lower number than. Basically the total time by the total size, although everything was transferred in the first seconds according to the output. The time is also not updated anymore after those 11 seconds.

Comment: It looks to me your `dd` behaves as if it had `conv=fdatasync` option enabled by default. I think if it didn't, it would exit like it happens in my previous link; then you would `sync` and have to wait anyway. Try to force synchronous writing with `oflag=dsync`. The overall average speed may be lower but the progress report should be accurate. Don't use very small `obs` in this case because `dd` will sync the target device after every `obs` of data.

Comment: Probably because it can't read the last block - the iso is unlikely to be a multiple of 4 megabytes in size. Use a smaller blocksize, or just use `cp` - no need to use `dd`.

Comment: @dirkt It's a myth. I have never lost this last block nor had any problems with it. Run `dd if=/etc/fstab bs=32M` and it will read this small file just fine unless you're short of memory.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is only `dd` syncing the data on-disk after the operation. In order to optimize IO operations, Linux often reads data in larger chunks than requested (read-ahead) and delay writes so they can be combined (dirty cache). At the end of the operation, either `dd` syncs the file on-disk or the kernel does it implicitly, and the process remains active until all the writes are finished.

If there is no other massive IO operations on the machine you should be able to estimate how much data there is left to write by looking at the "Dirty:" value in `/proc/meminfo` - this is the total amount of data pending to be written to disk.

The amount of data the system can leave unwritten in memory at any one time can be controlled with the following sysctl tuning knobs. By default only the ratios are used. You can define the value in percent (ratio) or bytes.

```
vm.dirty_background_ratio
vm.dirty_ratio
vm.dirty_background_bytes
vm.dirty_bytes
```

You will find the official documentation for these parameters here:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt

Comment: Does this mean that the `85.3 MB/s` is the reading-speed? That might explain why mine is super fast initially, and then drops over time.

Comment: Correct... If you send `USR1` signals to print progress you will see what `dd` thinks it wrote. IIRC the final status also prints before `dd` blocks so it's not real figures. It may be different with `fsync`/`fdatasync` as `conv=` option for the final status. Using `sync`/`dsync` in `oflags=` will avoid the sync delay but likely slow down the whole process too by avoiding write caches entirely.

Comment: I assume the answer is to just wait it out ?