# dd bytes differ. urandom versus zero Why?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

With:

- Kubuntu 22.04
  ~ 8000 GB ~ 8TB Usb Hard Disk Drive
  ~ 15 hours for 8TB with each dd command

dd --version
`dd (coreutils) 8.32`

Ran dd ... urandom:
`time sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sd_  bs=64K status=progress`
output

```
8001557168128 bytes (8.0 TB, 7.3 TiB) copied, 53987 s, 148 MB/s 
dd: error writing '/dev/sda': No space left on device 
122094166+0 records in 
122094165+0 records out 
8001563221504 bytes (8.0 TB, 7.3 TiB) copied, 54057 s, 148 MB/s
```

Ran dd ... zero:
`time sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd_  bs=64K status=progress`
output

```
8001543208960 bytes (8.0 TB, 7.3 TiB) copied, 53986 s, 148 MB/s 
dd: error writing '/dev/sda': No space left on device 
122094166+0 records in 
122094165+0 records out 
8001563221504 bytes (8.0 TB, 7.3 TiB) copied, 54057.4 s, 148 MB/s
```

For above 2 commands, it took almost the
same time ~ 53986 seconds ~ 15 hours.

Note the last line is the same 8001563221504 bytes.

But, first line of bytes are different:

```
+ 8001557168128 ~ 8000 GB, for urandom   
- 8001543208960 ~ 8000 GB, for zero   
---------------------------------------  
+      13959168 ~ 13.9 MB difference
```

dd ... urandom output was over 13 MBytes more.

How come the dd output first line
differs by over 13 MB?

Said differently,
Why did bytes differ between above 2 commands:
`dd ... urandom` and `dd ... zero`?

Answer (score 1):

These "first lines" are progress lines that were constantly updating. They are there because of `status=progress`. What you see at the end is the *last* state of the progress line before each respective `dd` printed the `No space left` error, printed the usual summary (independent from `status=progress`) and exited.

In your case the lines only mean that:

- in 53987 seconds the first `dd` copied 8001557168128 bytes,
- in 53986 seconds the second `dd` copied 8001543208960 bytes.

*By chance* the last updates of the respective progress lines happened at these exact values of time and amount of data. The differences between the two cases are not important. A slight fluctuation could have resulted in slightly different values.

Eventually each `dd` managed to write 8001563221504 bytes. This is what matters. I guess the progress lines were updated about once per second, but in both cases the summary was printed more than 60 s after the last update of the respective progress line [because of syncing](https://superuser.com/q/1220867/432690).

Comment: On a another topic to Kamil's answer ...   
there is a difference between above 2 outputs    
```dd ... urandom``` has:   
no decimal point and  
no 1/10 second digit, but 
```dd ... zero``` has it, example:  
  
```54057   s,``` 148 MB/s  for ```dd ... urandom``` and   
```54057.4 s,``` 148 MB/s  for ```dd ... zero```   
  
Based on above output:   
```dd ... urandom``` is running different code, different decimal precision, than 
```dd ... zero```